# SpringBoot Hibernate Inheritance @OneToOne does't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have been trying to solve this problem for 6 hours and I am dissapointed :(.
The problem is with @OneToOne because entities **ChildA** and **ChildB** might have the same **Test** record although I use @OneToOne(mappedBy).

```
@Entity
public class Test  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "test")
    private Parent parent;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

and below is an inheritance:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "test_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Test test;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
public class ChildA extends Parent {

}
```

```
@Entity
public class ChildB extends Parent {

}
```

and I created a record Test: `INSERT INTO Test (id) VALUES (1);`
then I created a record ChildA: `INSERT INTO ChildA (id, test_id) VALUES (1, 1);`
and finally: ChildB: `INSERT INTO ChildB (id, test_id) VALUES (1, 1);` and booom both use the same **test_id**. The **Test** record should be unique in parent class, and in all child classes but it is not unique.

Could you please help me out with that?

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to see in the `parent` attribute of your `test` object? You have two children which refers to the same id.

If a few children can have the same `test_id` you must use `@ManyToOne` relationship.